# Why is replace() method saving the state of the Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragment-backstack

I have a `BottomNavigationView` to navigate between 4 `Fragments`, the first one has a `RecyclerView`. When I select an item of the `BottomNavigationView` I use the `replace()` method to switch between the `Fragments`. What I don't understand is why is it that when I scroll the `RecyclerView`, go to another `Fragment` and go back to the `Fragment` with the `RecyclerView`, the scroll position stays the same as when I left the `Fragment` instead of going back to the top of the `RecyclerView`. Since I'm using `replace()` and not adding to the backstack shouldn't the fragment be reset? Here is my code:

```
private void initializeFragments() {

    homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    feedFragment = new FeedFragment();
    chatFragment = new ChatFragment();
    profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, homeFragment, "home")
            .commit();

}
```

---

```
private void setupBottomNavigation() {


        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {

            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.bottom_nav_home) {
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, homeFragment, "home")
                        .commit();


            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.bottom_nav_feed) {
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, feedFragment, "feed")
                        .commit();


            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.bottom_nav_chat) {
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, chatFragment, "chat")
                        .commit();


            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.bottom_nav_profile) {
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, profileFragment, "profile")
                        .commit();

            }

            return true;
        });
```

Comment: It looks like you're reusing the same fragment instances and this causes some quirks when you re-add them, in your case fragments view save state is restored (not to be confused with fragments save state).

Comment: Ok I think I understand, can I do it this way or should I not use the same fragment instance everytime I change fragments? Can you explain the difference between those save states? thank you

Comment: Aside from fragments `savedInstanceState` there's also its view save state - however its handled completely internally and you cannot alter it. When your fragment is removed fragment manager indeed doesn't store its state (you will receive `null` during `onCreate`) but fragment instance itself is keeping last views save state in internal variable and it will be used to restore views state after its created.

Comment: thank you, i understand now